# Role of NTC thermistor

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, integrated-circuit

I have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f24TTH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this schematic I don’t understand what the NTC does. When the resistors and the NTC get headed R1 is increased and RNTC is decreased and because R1 is increased, VBQ1 is decreased. But what does the NTC do? I know the collector current is temperature dependent, if we increase temperature collector current is increased. So is the NTC in some way regulating IC1?

Comment: What is the purpose of the circuit?

Comment: The exercise is to find the purpose of the circuit.

Comment: Well then you should not assume the circuit is an amplifier where the NTC is just a for compensation (after all, where is the external signal input?) It could also be a temperature measurement or thresholding circuit

Comment: Have you tried to simulate or calculate it? Any thoughts?

Comment: @winny I have posted my thoughts

Comment: The circuit seems to generate heat. Is there more to the circuit that is not shown? Like maybe an output or something?

Comment: No this is all it is.

Comment: Every resistor except the NTC will have fairly constant resistance no matter heat, but the NTC will become stable since no more current than R1+R2 will pass through it. So depending on R1 and R2, you will get a bit of heat or no heat at all. The BJT seems to be there to fill out the BoM cost budget...

Comment: What is a BoM cost budget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thermistor is for bias temperature compensation. In a transistor amplifier changes in temperature will affect the bias point, the higher the temperature, the higher the collector current for a particular base current. One way to compensate for this is to put a thermistor in the bias circuit to lower the bias with increased temperature.

This was more of a problem with Germanium transistor, so in early transistor radios you would often see a thermistor to control the bias of the class B output stage. See [this article](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electronics-world/class-b-transistor-power-output-circuits-november-1960-electronics-world.htm) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example to show how the characteristics of the CTN can be quasi-linearized.
Full-scale is been achieved although the CTN resistance characteristic is "exponential".
Probably a better circuit could be achieved.

[image]